# For twin primes $p$ and $q$, prove there is an integer $a$ such that $p|(a^2-q)$ if and only if there is an integer $b$ such that $q|(b^2-p)$.

Tags: number-theory, divisibility, twin-primes

For twin primes $p$ and $q$, prove there is an integer $a$ such that $p|(a^2-q)$ if and only if there is an integer $b$ such that $q|(b^2-p)$.

Algebraic substitution using $p=q+2$ and the definition of divisibility seems to go nowhere, are there other properties of twin primes that may aid in this proof?

Comment: You want to use quadratic reciprocity and the fact that they are different $\bmod 4$. I also don't know why this was downvoted but w/e , welcome to the site.

Comment: Ah, that'll do it! Didn't see that the divisibility statements implied quadratic residues. Thank you!

Comment: @Asinomas Hi could you explain this further? particularly what you mean by different mod4?

Comment: @Willtswhite Because $p = q + 2$, we know if we have $p\equiv 1\pmod{4} \implies q\equiv 3\pmod{4}$, and similarly $p\equiv 3\pmod{4}\implies q\equiv 1\pmod{4}$. From this you can apply quadratic reciprocity to obtain $$\left(\frac{p}{q}\right) = \left(\frac{q}{p}\right)$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a twin-prime pair $\ p\ $ and $\ q\ $, necessarily either $\ p\ $ is of the form $\ 4k+1\ $ and $\ q\ $ of the form $\ 4k+3\ $ or vice versa. In this case , we have $$\left(\frac{p}{q}\right)=\left(\frac{q}{p}\right)$$ which is exactly the content of the claim